# How to move xml query from tcp to udp

Tags: php, curl, udp

I used to create a template like:

```
$template = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
$template.= "<request>";
$template.= "   <auth>";
$template.= "       <userid>".$USER_ID."</userid>";
$template.= "       <apikey>".$API_KEY."</apikey>";
$template.= "   </auth>";
$template.= "   <language>".$LANGUAGE."</language>";
$template.= "   <task>";
$template.= "       <vertragid>".$VERTRAGID."</vertragid>";
$template.= "       <data>";
$template.= "           <countrycode>".$COUNTRYCODE."</countrycode>";
$template.= "       </data>";
$template.= "   </task>";
$template.= "</request>";
```

and used curl to fetch the data.

Now I have to connect via UDP port.

Can anybody give me a starting point or point me to an example how to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to connect using UDP??

Comment: The server requires it!!!!